# how to filter the relationship attributes in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

hi i have a model called `room` and another model called `roomAttribute` in room attribute i have price and size fields now i want to filter the rooms by price and when i send price i just want to show the attributes in price range but when i use whereHas or with it boths brings me all attributes when the condition comes true so here is what i tried and i want :

```
   return $query->with([
            'attributes' => function (Builder $q) use ($start_price,$end_price) {
            $q->where('price', '>',$start_price);
            $q->where('price', '<',$end_price);
            }
        ]);
```

and another try was

```
     return $query->whereHas('attributes', function (Builder $q) use ($start_price,$end_price) {
            $q->select('price');
            $q->where('price', '>',$start_price);
           $q->where('price', '<',$end_price);
        });
```

so in my db consider i have 3 rows :

```
"id": 1,
            "name": "test",
            "description": "test",
            "Attributes": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "room_id": 1,
                    "size": 20,
                    "price": 200,
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "room_id": 1,
                    "size": 20,
                    "price": 200,
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "room_id": 1,
                    "size": 55,
                    "price": 25000,

                }
            ]
```

so when i send price to this api with start_price of 100 and end price of 200 i just want to show the first 2 items of attributes and not the third one how can i achieve that ??

Comment: Your first clause is conflicting. You say the price has to be greater than the start price AND equal to the end price. (By the way, the double equals is not correct for WHERE clauses. You need a single equal, or it can be eliminated as that's the default comparison operator). The second is semi-correct, but you're saying it has to be more than start and less than end, but not equal. You want `>=` and `<=`

Comment: check my edited question that equal was wrong there even with equals it wont work

Answer (score -1):

Your query here:

```
return $query->whereHas('attributes', function (Builder $q) use ($start_price,$end_price) {
        $q->select('price');
        $q->where('price', '>',$start_price);
       $q->where('price', '<',$end_price);
    });
```

Says that the price has to be greater than the start price and less than the end price, but never equal. You want to change the query to check for "greater than or equal" and "less than or equal":

```
return $query->whereHas('attributes', function (Builder $q) use ($start_price,$end_price) {
        $q->select('price');
        $q->where('price', '>=',$start_price);
       $q->where('price', '<=',$end_price);
    });
```

Comment: Nope its yet bringing me the third object too

Comment: Is the price field in the database a varchar or integer/decimal/float field?

Comment: integer it works fine for start_price i mean if i send 0 it returns empty but when i send  some condition which is true for one field it returns all fields